# Video uploading not working in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on uploading the videos for my website. But i unable to do it. I have search many documents but i am fail to solve it. Can any one help me out to solve this problem?

I am getting an error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"

//Form code for video upload..

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'video' , 'files' => true)) !!}

```
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('video_name', 'Video Name : ') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name',null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('video_path', 'Select Video : ') !!}
        {!! Form::file('path', ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Upload Video')  !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

//Controller Code

public function store(Request $request){

```
    $data = $request->all();
    if ( $request->hasFile( 'path' ) ) {
        $file = $request->file( 'path' );
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $data[ 'path' ] = $name;
        $destination = '/public/videos';
        $request->file( 'path' )->move( base_path() . $destination, $name );
        return $name;
    }
    else {
        return '<script>alert("Fail")</script>';
    }
}
```

//The above code is working for images, doucments and audio but not working for videos.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check your php.ini

    `post_max_size` + 
    `upload_max_filesize` ? If you video is larger than what your php.ini allowed. That could be your problem.

Comment: Hello ihue. its working for me now. It was the size problem as you mentioned. But now i got another problem which is when i upload a video with max size it isnt play on the browser. Do you have any solution for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I can help. :)

Answer (score 7):

If your uploaded video is larger than the upload setting in your `php.ini` then you get this problem.

I suggest check your `php.ini` file and increase these directives as needed

---

`php.ini`

Example

```
post_max_size=200M
upload_max_filesize=200M
```

Comment: Hi ihue, i have already updated these fields. Now i can upload the max size video. but when i am going to play that video on browser it dose not play. Is the browser dose not support the max size or their is any other issue.